# Linux: Is it possible to get the last being opened time of all the files inside a folder?

Tags: linux

The title of this thread is kind of weird, let me explain what I mean:

Suppose I have lots of folders in my file systems that basically eat all the disk space. The feature is that we need to develop tools to delete some of the folders.

The question that how may I find/get the [last being opened time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8840/last-time-file-opened)(including the `atime`, `mtime` and `ctime`) of all the files inside a folder.

For example, there are 100 folders inside the file system, and each folder has more than 100000 files in it. If all the 10000 files under  **folder A**'s had not been accessed in the last 7 days, we could delete **folder A**.

I know we could iterate all the files inside all the folders, but that could be very slow. Just wondering if maybe there is a quicker way?

Comment: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/find-atime-872309/ combine this with the `-exec` argument of find to delete the matching files

Comment: @Mark Thanks for replying, it seems that the link you referred doesn't apply to my specific case. I would like to keep a folder if 1 of the 10000 files inside it was accessed within 7 days. Otherwise we could delete that folder. I trying to figure out not to iterate all the 10000 files to know that info.

Comment: Use a bash script to test the output of find to see how many results are returned. If they are below a certain number, run the rm command

Comment: In that case, it would not be a quicker way :( Since we have to iterate all the files inside the folder. In windows system, we could easily get the that information without iterate them.